# Getting error while installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting an error while installing SQL Server 2008. The error is like

> SQLServer SetUp requires .NetFramework 3.5 to be installed

But .NET framework 3.5,SP1,VS2008 sp1 is already installed. I have checked in control panel also.
Because of this error I am not able to do daily tasks.

Please help me, where am going wrong?

Comment: You need to install .NET Framework 3.5 because the software trying to install is dependent on .NET Framework.
http://www.filehippo.com/download_dotnet_framework_3/

Comment: I have already installed 3.5 framework

Comment: I'm having the same problem, nothing works. Windows 2008 R2 with .NET 3.5 SP1 installed and still I get the error as if it isn't installed. All I can find is morons telling other people to install .NET 3.5, yeah, duh. Already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you install .NET Framework 3.5
sql server installer still ask you to install .NET Framework 3.5.
If you install sql server 2008 Standard ed in windows -server 2008 R2, .NET Framework 3.5 is already built in with windows.
`Just go to server manager, click Add Feature and enable it. After that, you can install SQL Server 2008.`

Comment: Thank you for your solution.My PC configurations,OS:WIndows 7,and am trying to install SQLServer2008 Dev edition.So can you guide me ,how can i enable the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This bug had already reported to microsoft see here.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/354980/sql-server-2008-setup-requires-microsoft-net-framework-3-5

and solution that helped was

The setup has been successfully completed after installation of .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 (BETA) and Windows Installer 4.5. It was also nessary to install PowerShell after that.

Go ahead and download the required software and then try again installing.

Comment: I have tried your solution,but still it is throwing same error :(

Comment: @user1676709 you tried by installing all three s/w along with windows installer?

Comment: Windows Installer 5.0 & Powershell is already installed in my PC.I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In the installation folder you have some files and three folder (ia64, x64, x86). When I copied the installation folder of SQL Server 2008 I excluded the ia64 and x64 folder.

The solution that worked for me was to not exclude the x64 folder. Maybe it is possible you have missing files. I would download or copy the installation files again!